# Should I use defensive copies in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, immutability

I was playing around with mutability, and I came up with the following code in which an immutable object can be cast to a mutable one.

```
- (NSString *) getaString {
    NSMutableString * string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [string appendString:@"This "];
    [string appendString:@"was mutable."];
    return string;                          
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Get a string returns an NSString, which is then cast to a mutable string with a compler warning.
    NSMutableString * string = [self getaString];
    [string appendString:@" And apparently still is"];
    _showText.text = string;
}
```

or with no compiler warning

```
- (NSArray *) getaString {
    NSMutableString * string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [string appendString:@"This "];
    [string appendString:@"was mutable."];
    //Cast to NSString.
    NSString * immutableString = string;
    NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:immutableString, nil];
    return array;                          
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableString * string = [[self getaString] objectAtIndex:0];
    [string appendString:@" And apparently still is"];
    _showText.text = string;
}
```

The UITextField shows the whole string of "This was mutable. And apparently still is", with no compiler warning.  I've seen multiple SO posts that recommend simply casting or using mutable objects as immutable objects, but as I've just shown, that can be dangerous.  Also, the cast still works without the array, but I do get a compiler warning.

My question is, should I be considering using java style defensive copies?  I haven't seen any mention of defensive copies in objective C, and all I could find in Apple's documentation was a vague mention that [it’s best to adopt some defensive programming practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH5.).  I'm concerned both about security and about protecting against careless coding.

Comment: Where in this code do you even attempt making an `immutable` string?  You're acting as if you're surprised that `appendString` works on `NSMutableString`... it's supposed to.

Comment: I agree with @nhgrif - why are you surprised that a mutable string acts like a mutable string? But yes, if you're done mutating it, copy it. Accidental mutability aside, the framework can make optimizations if it knows you don't want to mutate it anymore.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define%3Amutable

Comment: There is no cast in the code you posted. What do you mean by "the following code in which an immutable object can be cast to a mutable one"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to the example without the array, but I didn't include that code.  I agree, it was unclear, and I have now updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you've given is misleading.

You are storing a `NSMutableString` in an array and you are taking it out. Why would you expect the string to be immutable after that?

However there are cases in which defensive copies are pretty much a standard in Objective-C.

Consider a class (let's call it `CustomClass`) defining a property for an `NSString` and a method to print it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
- (void)printTheString;
```

Now, since `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`, a client of this class could potentially do something like:

```
CustomClass *anObject = [CustomClass new];
NSMutableString *aMutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hey!"];
anObject.aString = aMutableString;
[anObject printTheString]; // Hey!
[aMutableString appendString:@" Got you!"];
[anObject printTheString]; // Hey! Got you!
```

which can be dangerous in some cases.

It has then become common practice to use the `copy` attribute, instead of `strong`, for immutable classes with a mutable subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;
```

In this way a defensive copy is made when the string is assigned, preventing the client to mess with the object later on.

The previous example would then print `Hey!` both times.

It's also worth noting that for most of this classes sending `copy` to an immutable object returns the same object, instead of an actual copy. In this way you can have your cake and eat it too, since the copy will be performed only when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer of what I was trying to ask.  I had wondered what the "copy" field was for.  Are there other examples you can think of where defensive copies are preferred?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure whether you *should* make defensive copies in Obj-c, but it is possible to make mutable copies of an immutable string, and it is possible to make immutable versions of a mutable string.

There aren't any immutable strings in your code, by the way. NSMutableStrings in an NSArray are still mutable, so you aren't doing any conversion. The array is the thing that cannot have objects appended to it.

Here's why: The array is just holding a *pointer* to the NSMutableString, not the actual object, so you're not changing the contents of the array by changing the contents of the string, because the memory address pointed to by the array stays the same.

Example:

```
NSString *original = @"Hello, world!";

// putting the original in a mutable string
NSMutableString *copy = [original mutableCopy];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:copy, nil];

// the object in the array can still be modified
[[array objectAtIndex:0] appendString:@" Goodbye, cruel world!"];

// make an immutable version of the mutable string
NSString *copyOfTheCopy =[NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:0]];

NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);

// just to make sure...
[[array objectAtIndex:0] appendString:@"Got you!"];

NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"%@", copyOfTheCopy);
```

The output should be:

```
2013-11-03 21:16:06.099 SomeProject[7045:303] Hello, world! Goodbye, cruel world!
2013-11-03 21:16:06.100 SomeProject[7045:303] Hello, world! Goodbye, cruel world!Got you!
2013-11-03 21:16:06.100 SomeProject[7045:303] Hello, world! Goodbye, cruel world!
```

Another answer given by **Gabriele Petronella** caused me to make a change that gets rid of one of those gotchas with pointers. This one doesn't use a pointer to the NSMutableString and instead makes a new string from the old one. Sorry I can't vote you up yet, you taught me something :)

Comment: SO is all about learning, so I'm glad to hear that. Anyway you got part of my explanation wrong. `[[array objectAtIndex:0] copy];` will indeed return a **mutable** copy of the object, since the object you are sending `copy` to is mutable.

Comment: I changed it. I think it would be correct to say that stringWithString returns an immutable object, if it is used to initialize an immutable one. The Apple docs say this: **Return Value**
A string created by copying the characters from aString.

Comment: Now it's correct. `stringWithString:` returns an immutable string in when sent to `NSString` and a mutable one when sent to `NSMutableString`. This is also the reason why the return type of constructor methods is `instancetype` (and used to be `id`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to obtain an immutable `NSString` from an `NSMutableString`, you can do something like this:

```
NSString *anImmutableString = [NSString stringWithString: aMutableString];
```

So if we take your original code in the question, and I'm going to assume that your `viewDidLoad` is where you want an immutable string:

```
- (NSArray *) getaString {
    NSMutableString * string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [string appendString:@"This "];
    [string appendString:@"was mutable."];
    NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string, nil];
    return array;                          
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:[[self getaString] objectAtIndex:0]];
    //[string appendString:@" And apparently still is"];
    _showText.text = string;
}
```

Now, if you still want to append to `string` in `viewDidLoad`, you can, but you'd have to do it differently (the same way you append to any other `NSString`).  It'd look something like this:

```
NSString *newString = [string stringByAppendingString:@" And apparently still is"];
```

Now look at the contents of the variables.

```
string = "This was mutable." //as you built it from an NSMutableString in the getaString method
newString = "This was mutable. And apparently still is" //as built from calling "stringByAppendingString" method on your variable string in viewDidLoad
```

It's important to note that the contents of `newString` are quite misleading here.  `newString` is not an `NSMutableString`.  It's a regular `NSString`.  Calling `stringByAppendingString` returns an `NSString` that is the result of appending the argument you send to the end of the `NSString` you're calling the method on.  (And the contents of the `NSString` you called the method on remain unchanged--it's immutable).

If you would like `newString` to be an `NSMutableString`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
NSMutableString *newString = [[string stringByAppendingString:" And apparently still is"] mutableCopy];
```